# JQuery UI Tabs : How to find target container of currently active tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there any way I can find the target container of the active tab of Jquery UI tabs?

Comment: What do you mean by 'target container'? The button?

Comment: I mean the target div of the tab. The one which gets loaded in active panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

active container has attribute aria-expanded set to true. so to get the active container you can use:

```
var container_active= $('[aria-expanded="true"]');
```

or you can get id of currently active container using:

```
var active_container_id=$('.ui-state-active a').attr('href').replace('#','')
```

Comment: Yeah. That's right. But I have other tabs inside the target container. I want the top level target.